# General last resort(?) RECOVERY MODE alternative for NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, proprietary

What to do if the recommend way to install the latest driver in the `System Settings` > `Software and updates` or `Ubuntu software` FAILS?

*e.g. what most answers in [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) and many others aims at.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No exact details provided, as the details may change with time - the intention here is to keep this answer relevant as long as possible:*

1. Boot into recovery mode,
   e.g. while restarting the computer, early, at the "BIOS boot display"; hold or tap `ESC`, hold `SHIFT`-key or whatever action makes the grub boot menu appear, select the latest recovery mode.
2. Run `fsck` and `network` options in the menu before launching a `root shell` (those are menu alternatives in recovery mode!).
3. Install e.g. lynx or links (text mode web browsers!) with apt if you do not already have one of them, unless you can use the direct link below for `wget <link>`.
4. Use lynx/ links/ wget to download the driver from nvidia.com .
   This MIGHT be the link: Check http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/latest.txt,
   append the file content to `http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/`to create a direct link)
5. Remove all of any previously installed drivers.
   E.g. `bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.31.run --uninstall` or
   check `dpkg --list | grep -i nvidia` and use apt / apt-get to purge relevant portions of what is listed.
6. Install the driver you DL:ed.
   E.g. `bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.50.run --install`
7. type `reboot` and press `ENTER`