# Nvidia on Windows and Intel on Ubuntu (dual boot system)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics

I am using Ubuntu alongside windows for 5 years, even though, I am not very technical on it. I have Nvidia on my windows, I am facing a never-ending-famous issue while Ubuntu boot(flickering, black screen, can't enter into Ubuntu). At the moment my Ubuntu is showing black screen and can't access to tty. I tried every solutions in internet, but nothing worked for me. I think Ubuntu crashed or something and I am going for a reinstall.

Many internet solutions says AMD or Intel are THE BEST graphics than Nvidia for Ubuntu. Also, I learned Nvidia is better for Windows. Anyway, I was ready to switch my graphics to AMD or Intel, but on a final thought, my question here,

1. is there any way to stop this boot issue by retaining Nvidia on Windows only and using only Intel on Ubuntu only? Or
2. should I completely remove Nvidia and install AMD or use built-in Intel graphics?

I hope there will any solution for this. If first question applies, can someone please give me steps to this?.

Comment: @Nmath Yes, my system is a laptop is Dell inspiron 14 5458, 64bit, with Intel HD graphics 5500 and NVIDIA GeForce 920M. The link you have provided is my issue, but I tried all those solutions, but nothing resolving my problem. And what do you mean by my "Ubuntu installation is misconfigured"? I have installed from live USB using 64bit installer. What should I take care while installing Ubuntu if you suspect my installation is misconfigured?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue. You haven't really described the problem in a lot of details. Specifics about what you tried and why it didn't work for you would be helpful. Do you have dual boot config with Windows?  Is your installation media valid?  As you can tell from the link, this could be any number of things.  You have to scientifically test hypothesis and figure out the true root of your problem. It could be that you're doing something wrong but you don't know it's wrong. So that's very hard to identify.

Comment: @Nmath My laptop is dual boot with windows. My problem started with screen flickering constantly after selecting Ubuntu from the grub menu. Then I upgraded to 18.04 and initially it was working fine, suddenly one day screen started to flicker again (possibly after software updates, but not sure). I tried many solutions like nomodeset fix, lightdm fix, remove and install nvidia, and a lot than I can remember. I am totally tired of this issue for good few years. That's why I am going to switch graphics. Is there any solution to my first question? or second? That's all I wanted to know.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong. New linux users sometimes try to do under the hood tasks in the same way they are used to doing in Windows and end up breaking things. There's a learning curve. No you cannot "switch graphics". You don't have AMD hardware.  I don't think your problems have *anything* to do with NVIDIA and if you have hybrid graphics you probably can't disable that either. If you can, you'll probably have to do it in your BIOS.

Comment: My suggestion to you is to take better notes for what you're doing and what exactly happens as a result. Make a habit of reading terminal output and if you can't understand something, look it up until you do. If you can't document and understand what's happening you won't be able to convey it to others to effectively ask for help nor will you be able to discern what help applies to your situation when you try to fix a problem. If you're going down a list of fixes without understanding what they do or if they are relevant, I promise your just making new problems which accumulate.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188552/general-last-resort-recovery-mode-alternative-for-nvidia-driver

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1: Try connecting an outside monitor via HDMI when getting the black screen. Sometimes(not always) the case is that the main desktop image goes on the outside monitor leaving the main one blank which is why it is black. If this helps then you can go to display settings an choose your main screen as your primary screen again.